# Matlab transpose values in a structure within a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, transpose, cell-array

I successfully created a moving window of n=85 for my data and put the windows in a cell array:

```
n = 37886;
cell_array=cell(n,1);
a = 1:n;
for T=1:n-84
  M=a(T:T+84);
    tmpstruct=struct('M',M);
    cell_array{T}=tmpstruct;
end
```

However, I need to transpose M, which is the data of window values located within the structure within the cell array. That is, instead of the vector of window values being 1x85, I want them to be 85x1.

I've attempted transposing with this:

```
cell_array = cellfun(@transpose,cell_array,'UniformOutput',false);
```

But this code doesn't work for me.

Any feedback on how to transpose my windows will be greatly appreciated. I need to transpose 252 cell arrays, so doing this manually is out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I clearly understood, what about:

```
n = 37886;
cell_array=cell(n,1);
a = 1:n;
for T=1:n-84
  M=a(T:T+84);
    tmpstruct=struct('M',M'); % Modified line to transpose windows!
    cell_array{T}=tmpstruct;
end
```

If you prefer named functions:

```
n = 37886;
cell_array=cell(n,1);
a = 1:n;
for T=1:n-84
  M=a(T:T+84);
    tmpstruct=struct('M',transpose(M)); % Modified line to transpose windows!
    cell_array{T}=tmpstruct;
end
```

Comment: The code you copied is the code I am using to put my data in windows of size 85. The windows are in a structure within a cell array; I need to transpose the windows. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: You missed a little ' sign inside my code that will transpose your windows. Try to run it and tell me if this is what you want.

Comment: `'` is not transpose; it is conjugate transpose

Comment: The OP asked this: "That is, instead of the vector of window values being 1x85, I want them to be 85x1.", and my code does -exactly- what he asks for.

Comment: Tommaso Belluzzo- your code works and indeed does exactly what I ask for!

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo _my code does -exactly- what he asks for_ except if `a` is complex (I assume `a = 1:n` in OP's code is just an example). To just transpose, use `.'`